# Could two brands share the same DSL modem firmware?

Tags: modem, firmware, dsl

Tried to update DSL modem (Telewell TW-EA501) firmware, but received "Server Error A file system error was detected on the RomPager server. Return to last page" - message. Did Googling on the string and the links pointed to ZyXEL modems? Could the two brands share the same firmware?

Comment: yes, they could be manufactured by the same company under different brands

Comment: Funny, there are arguments like "I used to have a ZyXEL modem, but it was a piece of s***. Now I've got a Telewell and life is good." Or vice versa, but the firmware is more or less identical. And the hardware got to be very similar too, I guess.