# Can't access web interface of modem (tw-ea501(b)) [fixed]

Tags: modem

I have a Telewell TW-AE501 (b) modem. It works, as in that it connects me to the internet. But once in a while it loses the connection and has to connect again (the internet and ADSL lights go off and start blinking to reconnect).

I wanted to check the firmware because [one of the first results in google](http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic157042.html)  talks about a similar problem and suggests a firmware upgrade. But to do that I need access to the webinterface of the modem, and that doesn't work.

The manual says the default IP for the webinterface is `192.168.0.254` but that times out (I did turn off my Windows Firewall).

I also tried

- `192.168.1.1`
- `192.168.100.1`
- `192.168.1.254`

Now I'm thinking of the reset button. But I don't live here (just temporary now) so I don't know anything about any settings I should know for the internet connection.

So my questions are:

- <del>Can I reset the modem without losing any important settings?</del>
- **Are there any other things I can try to connect to the web interface?**

**update:**
I tried the reset button, but nothing changed. I still can't see the web interface.

**Update 2**
(After another reset) I found out that it matters in which port the computer is connected. In port 1 and 2 I can now access the webinterface, but not in port 3 and 4. So now I updated the firmware and hope it will be ok. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Run `cmd` and enter `ipconfig`. What is the local IP of your connection?

Comment: i'm not sure which one but i think the first one:

ethernet adapter local area connection:
ip4: 85.157.235.170

ethernet adapter local area connection2:
ip4: 5.179.120.89

Thanks for cleaning up my question. And sorry for my slow answer.. the connection is dying all the time.

Comment: I thought this piece of crap is sold just in Finland.

Comment: "Timing out" is the feature of Telewell's site. ;-) I know had once that particular model. This is shameless product promotion: http://www.verkkokauppa.com/fi/product/41783/cxjsx/ZyXEL-P-660HN-T1A-ADSL2-reititin-tukiasema

Comment: Other choices - just stay away from Telewell. http://www.verkkokauppa.com/fi/catalog/336c/ADSL-verkkoon

Comment: yes I'm in Finland, and it is made in Finland. So you just say give up and get something else? For some reason it loses the internet connection every few minutes the last days.

Comment: @Niels, you may want to post your update 2 as an answer and mark it as accepted when the self-accept time limit passes.

Comment: Never ever "Telehell" again: http://superuser.com/questions/264060/could-two-brands-share-the-same-dsl-modem-firmware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it matters in which port the computer is connected. In port 1 and 2 I can now access the webinterface, but not in port 3 and 4. So now I updated the firmware.

The internet connection still drops very frequently but I guess that is just because the brand sucks.

Thanks for the comments.